# Editing existing data in form. NextJs/Prisma CRUD

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

So I am working on a CRUD operation with nextjs for client side, prisma for table model with postgres database. I am working the ability to edit existing data with new data in my form on the client side. I am able to edit the data successfully but the page need to refresh to see the changes. This is my first time working with update side of CRUD and not sure if my approach is correct. My though process was the update part is similar to creating part. I am unsure if what I am doing is a correct approach.

prisma update endpoint:

```
const {id, name, courseDetails} = req.body;
try{
    const updateClass = await prisma.class.update({
        where: {
            id: parseInt(id),
        },
        data: {
            name,
            courseDetails,
        }
    })
    res.status(200).json(updateClass);
    console.log(updateClass);
    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

}

Edit Page:

```
const EditClass = ({ closeModal, classes }) => {
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    id: classes.id,
    name: classes.name,
    courseDetails: classes.courseDetails,
});

const handleEditClass = async () => {
    const response = await axios.post("/api/class/edit", formData);
    console.log(response);
    refreshData();
}


<form>
  <label className="label" htmlFor="name">
        Name
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" 
        defaultValue={classes.name}
        onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, name: 
         e.target.value })}
    />

<label className="label" htmlFor="course-details">
        Course Details
</label>
    <input type="text" name="editCourseDetails"  
        defaultValue={classes.courseDetails}
        onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, 
        courseDetails: e.target.value })}
    />
</form>
```

The code above work but I need to refresh the page to see the new data. Can someone give me some feedback how to show new data in realtime or should I approach it differently?

Comment: What does `refreshData` do currently?

Comment: I found a work around for this. So Instead of assign each input in form data, I assign each one with it own state and set each data to target that value which render immediately when data has change.